# IdentityServer4 - Login via ADFS without logon prompt appearing

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application, identityserver4, adfs

With the use of IdentityServer4 and the OIDC protocol, I've managed to get my SPA and my .net core web api authenticating against a sql server user store, as well as ADFS which is great. However, when the user first clicks the 'Continue with ADFS' button, the login prompt is shown asking the user for their credentials. My understanding was that with the use of openId connect and IdentityServer, we could add external identity providers such as ADFS to our IdentityServer application and if ADFS is chosen for login with the user already logged in to ADFS via their local machine, then the authentication would happen seamlessly without the need to input windows user credentials again. There are other steps in order to achieve this of course, like linking the ADFS UserId with our SQL Database User Id table, but overall my understanding was that this would be entirely possible.

After a user logs out from an ADFS login, the next time the user chooses to log back in with ADFS, the 'Challenge' method that is run within my IdentityServer application to initiate the redirect to ADFS often recognises that the user has already logged in recently and therefore just logs them right in without the need for their credentials again.

My question is - is it actually possible to avoid the initial login prompt altogether? Or will the browser insist that credentials are provided if the user hasn't logged into the application for a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is possible but it may involve specific browser config in ADFS and also may require your IDP to be in the intranet zone in Windows Internet settings.

Check out these articles:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-intranet-forms-based-authentication-for-devices-that-do-not-support-wia
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-browser-wia

Comment: Thanks for the answer - you've steered me into the right direction. Much appreciate it!